# TreeView that holds Objects

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Is there a way to have a `TreeView` hold `Objects` instead of a simple `string`?  Similar to how a `ListBox` functions?

Or is there a control that is visibly similar to a `TreeView` that is capable of holding an `Object`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to hold an object in a TreeNode, you can use the Tag property.

```
TreeNode node;
node.Tag = myObject;
```

That will hold an object that you can retrieve anytime.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `TreeNode`, set it's text to whatever you want, assign an object to `Tag` property and add it to `TreeView`

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a subclass of TreeNode with a property to hold your object.  Here is a generic version:

```
public class MyTreeNode<T>:TreeNode {
    private T data;

    public T Data {
        get {
            return data;
        }
        set {
            data = value;
            Text = data.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case I'm also setting the TreeNode's text when the data value is set, though more code would be required if you were changing the stored object's state and wanted the TreeNode's Text to reflect that.